# UITabBarController with conditional UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, conditional-statements

When a bar item is pressed, I would like to select which `UIViewController` in a `UITabBarController` to show based on a condition (How to check user is logged in or not).

Comment: What is the bar button ?

Comment: I meant the Tab Bar Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a UIViewController as a child of UITabBarController, which again adds either a LoginViewController or a UserViewController as a child using the following code as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // self.signedIn = [storage boolForKey:@"signed_in"];

    // remove first if needed
    for (UIViewController * child in self.childViewControllers){
        [self hideContentController:child];
    }

    if(self.signedIn){
        [self displayContentController:self.loginController];
    } else {
        [self displayContentController:self.userController];
    }

    self.signedIn = !self.signedIn;
}

- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
    content.view.frame = self.view.frame; // 2
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}

- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
    [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at  [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)  There are two methods

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

So that every time you click one of the tab bar these delegates will be called and you can do the rest of your actions.

Comment: I guess my problem is more that i want to choose which UIViewController to show when pressing a certain bar button item, based on the user is logged in or not, either a User Profile or a Login ViewController. With that delegate you can only control if the thing connected to a bar item should be selected or not.. not the content of it?

Comment: You may change the view controller on there. Or the other solution might be to present loginviewcontroller on top of UITabBarController if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Another approach may be handling user profile and login on a controller just like you did. You create a method on your view controller so that when user tab the tab bar tabBarController:didSelectViewController: will be fired and call the newly created method to check if the user is actually is logged in every time user tab on tabbar item.

Comment: I tried to change the view controller in the shouldSelectViewController but it says you can only set view controllers which are already in the list of view controllers for the tab bar. Maybe i have to user a third view controller with a contentView. I still want to show the toolbar when showing either user profile or login view.  If you have an example of how to do this that would be great.